# Only First child can access methods and properties not Descendants in Prototypal inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototype-chain

```
let animal = {
  eats: true,
  walk() {
    alert("Animal walk");
  }
};

let rabbit = {
  jumps: true,
  __proto__: animal
};

let longEar = {
  earLength: 10,
  __proto__: rabbit
};

// walk is taken from the prototype chain
longEar.walk(); // Animal walk
alert(longEar.jumps); // true (from rabbit)`
```

In the above example Only Rabbit can access properties and methods of animals because its first child not longEar because its child of rabbit.
Suppose we created below example

```
let horse = {
  jumps: true,
  __proto__: animal
};

let longHoof = {
  hoofLength: 10,
  __proto__: horse
};
```

In simple words,
Whoever inherit first child can only access from animals.

**Animals:**

- Horse (must access animals properties and methods)
  meanwhile **longHoof** Inherit Horse (should not access properties and methods of Animals)

There is no way i can stop this
Is there any special method or trick to prevent it?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? "There is no way i can stop this Is there any special method or trick to prevent it?"
Do you want some way for the nth child to access animal?

Comment: Don't use [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto), take a look at [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) instead.

Comment: Not working, class is syntactic sugar

Comment: @EspressoCode I want to prevent nth child to accessing properties and methods of Animals. Only first child can access

Comment: "_class is syntactic sugar_" it definitely isn't, classes are capable to do things you can't do with any other way, ex. private instance properties and subclassing of some native constructors. The linked MDN documentation of `__proto__` is so full of red, that should really ring the bell ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, you can set the prototype of the top layer to {}. We need to use `Object.assign()` to get a copy of the rabbit object and not change the original rabbit.

```
let animal = {
  eats: true,
  walk() {
    alert("Animal walk");
  }
};

let rabbit = {
  jumps: true,
  __proto__: animal
};

let longEar = {
  earLength: 10,
  __proto__: Object.setPrototypeOf(Object.assign({}, rabbit), {})
};


// walk is taken from the prototype chain
longEar.walk(); // Uncaught TypeError: longEar.walk is not a function
alert(longEar.jumps); // true (from rabbit)`
rabbit.walk() // rabbit can still walk
```